# Pyside, TableView and pandas, add row

Tags: python, pandas, append, pyside, qtableview

I try to show and modify information of a dataframe with a QTableView.
I can modify rows, and changes are ok in the model but when I try to add a new row, nothing was saved in the model... In my code, I try to add [1, 1, 1] whith the insertRow function... No warning or error... So where is my mistake?

My code :

```
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, v_data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = v_data
    
    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable|Qt.ItemIsEnabled|Qt.ItemIsEditable
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(),index.column()] = value
            return True

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
                value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
                return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])
    def insertRow(self, ajout):
        row = len(self._data)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self._data.append(ajout)
        print(self._data)
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        return row


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        container = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.addButton = QPushButton("test")
        self.addButton.pressed.connect(self.add_row)
        self.search = QLineEdit()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.search)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        container.setLayout(layout)

        df_data = pd.DataFrame(
            [
                [1, 9, 2],
                [1, 0, -1],
                [3, 5, 2],
                [3, 3, 2],
                [5, 8, 9],
            ],
            columns=["A", "B", "C"],
            index=["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", "Row 5"],
        )

        self.model = TableModel(df_data)
        self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(0) # Search all columns.
        self.proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.table.setModel(self.proxy_model)
        self.search.textChanged.connect(self.proxy_model.setFilterWildcard)


        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(1024, 600))
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
    
    def add_row(self):
        self.model.insertRow([1, 1, 1])
 
        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
        print('success')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is in the line you try to append the data to your pd.DataFrame

`self._data.append(ajout)`

First of all, as pandas says this is a deprecated function so if you want to add some data you should use `concat()`.

Anyway, since you want to keep the name of the indexes, you must replace that line with this one:

`self._data.loc["Row" + str(row+1)] = ajout`

This specifies that you want the next row to have the data you intend to add.

Here is the whole code:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel, QSize
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QApplication
import sys
import pandas as pd

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, v_data):
        super().__init__()

        self._data = v_data
    
    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable|Qt.ItemIsEnabled|Qt.ItemIsEditable
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(),index.column()] = value
            return True

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
                value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
                return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])
    def insertRow(self, ajout):
        row = len(self._data)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        print(self._data, "\n\n") # Before adding
        self._data.loc["Row" + str(row+1)] = ajout
        print(self._data, "\n\n") # After
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        return row


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        container = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.addButton = QPushButton("test")
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
        self.search = QLineEdit()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.search)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        container.setLayout(layout)

        df_data = pd.DataFrame(
            [
                [1, 9, 2],
                [1, 0, -1],
                [3, 5, 2],
                [3, 3, 2],
                [5, 8, 9],
            ],
            columns=["A", "B", "C"],
            index=["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", "Row 5"],
        )
        self.model = TableModel(df_data)
        self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(0) # Search all columns.
        self.proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.table.setModel(self.proxy_model)
        self.search.textChanged.connect(self.proxy_model.setFilterWildcard)


        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(1024, 600))
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
    
    def add_row(self):
        self.model.insertRow([1, 1, 1])
 
        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
        print('success')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I hope this fix your problem, tell me if it doesn't work for you.